# Pageable sorting not working for Spring Data JPA when using named queries

Tags: sorting, jpa, pagination, spring-data, named-query

I got to grips with using Spring Data JPA however I stumbled upon an issue, searched all the net but still didn't find an answer.  I got the repository working and even the paging and sorting.  However, it seems that when I do the same, but specifying a named query in the @Query annotation, rather than letting Spring generate the query at runtime, the sortable part of the Pageable object is completely ignored.  I can confirm this as the query generated by Hibernate does not have an "ORDER BY" clause in the latter case.

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long>
{           
    @Query(name = "Transaction.findParentTransactionsByStatus", countName = "Transaction.findCountParentTransactionsByStatus")
    public Page<Transaction> findParentTransactionsByStatus(@Param(value = "status") TransactionStatus status, Pageable pageable);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Can you post the actual HQL from your named query Transaction.findParentTransactionsByStatus?

The reason I am asking is, I encountered this same issue and it was because I had an extra end parenthesis ")" in my HQL. For some reason, it was being accepted as a valid HQL, but when passing the sort via Pageable, it was not including the sort column. My solution was to remove that extra parenthesis and it worked

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Had the same problem with an orphan parenthesis ")".